# Pretty way to show console output in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have rmarkdown files which I use for a website. I need to show the console output eg for statistical results. It is pretty ugly. The output from the markdown is html.

I know I can display pretty tables but is there a way of outputting console output in a less ugly way?

The ugliness is as follows:

```
## 
##  Spearman's rank correlation rho
## 
## data:  EndoCr$Midazolam and EndoCr$Fentanyl
## S = 186290, p-value = 0.2429
## alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
## sample estimates:
##        rho 
## -0.1178547
```

How can I make standard console output beautiful?

Comment: You can reformat output using CSS.